# local block variable for NSOperationQueue's addOperationWithBlock

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

How to use local block variable `offDownloadBlock` to addOperationWithBlock method of `NSOperationQueue`?

```
void (^offDownloadBlock)(NSString*, NSDictionary*);
offDownloadBlock = ^(NSString* key, NSDictionary* obj) {...};

NSOperationQueue *q = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[q addOperationWithBlock:offDownloadBlock(key, obj)];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for doing this. NSOperationQueue's -addOperationWithBlock: is defined as `- (void)addOperationWithBlock:(void (^)(void))block` which means the block takes no parameters and returns nothing. You can use this in your code like so:

```
NSString *key = @"Some key";
NSDictionary *obj = // Some dictionary;
[q addOperationWithBlock:^(){
    // your code goes here
    // use your key and obj here to do something that will run on the queue
}];
```

Edit to comment: If you want to make a recursive block, you have to call the block within the block. The only way to do such a thing is to define your block like this:

```
__block void (^myBlock)();
myBlock = ^(){
    NSLog(@"Running"); // This will run forever
    myBlock();
};
myBlock();
```

I'm going to say this is likely not what you want to do though in almost any case.

Comment: I understand that, but I want this block be called recursively. Meaning, I want to call `offDownloadBlock` inside `offDownloadBlock`